# TypeScript avoid repeated class properties when using default values

Tags: typescript, oop

Let's say I've got this interface:

```js
// foo.d.ts
export default interface IFoo {
  bar: number;
  faz: string;
  moo: {
    cat: boolean;
    cow: boolean;
  };
}
```

and I make a class (model) based on that:

```js
// fooModel.ts
import IFoo from "./interfaces/foo";

export default class FooModel implements IFoo {
  // now I don't like this
  bar = 0;
  faz = "";
  moo = {
    cat: false,
    cow: true
  }

  // optional property because default values
  // I also don't like this because I have to type the prop name like 3 times
  constructor(_foo?: IFoo) {
    if(_foo === undefined) return;
    this.bar = _foo.bar;
    this.faz = _foo.faz;
    this.moo = {
      cat: _foo.moo.cat,
      cow: _foo.moo.cow
    }
  }
}
```

and I call it like this

```
// fooController.ts
import FooModel from "./fooModel";
import IFoo from "../interfaces/foo";

export default class FooController {
  getFoo(params?: object) {
    return new FooModel(params)
  }
}
```

This is so much work just to get something with default values. As you can see, I have to type the `cat` and `cow` property like 4 times for it to properly initialize. This will result in a lot of clutter when you have a large model.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to type the properties in `FooModel`, their types are already defined in `IFoo`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyyARnFAFzIgCuAtsdANyHLwBelAzmFKAObMitbJQJEiCOGErFsAGwhwQg8QkwB3GfMXKWAX2Z78+BHLidOyLJgCymACYQ5yYLQAOC2hHCWM2PCxEpFDIALzIAIwqROxhyABEMNjx0cjCOOG4yJLSyDzUEAA02RqU8HKcKAb4RkA

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, indeed, but I want them to have default values.. which is not possible with interfaces

Comment: Then it's even less clear to me what your problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated the question for you with your comment implemented

Comment: *"I don't like this"* - tough? You can't put default values in interfaces because *they don't exist at runtime*. You could use something like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyyARnFAFzIgCuAtsdANyHLwBelAzmFKAObMitbJQJEiCOGErFsAGwhwQg8QkwB3GfMXKWAX2Z78+BHLidOyLJgCymACYQ5yYLQAOC2hHCWM2PCwSmCDcUNQIYJhQABSB4m7UxHLACCRkyAC8yACMADRxRAlJKaxwbJnIAEQw2JX54vGJyanCOFm4yJLSyDzUELmdGpTwcpwoevXiAJR4RkZAA, or just shorten to `this.moo = _foo.moo`. Or if you want to use modules instead, *use modules instead*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In my opinion modules are much harder to manage than classes, so thats why I use classes to comply with OOP. I feel like classes make the code easier to manage, if you got a good OOP module example, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
type PropertiesOnly<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : T[K]
}

export type IFoo = PropertiesOnly<FooModel>

// For your particular example, it's also safe to just do following:
// export type IFoo = FooModel

export default class FooModel {
  bar = 0;
  faz = "";
  moo = {
    cat: false,
    cow: true
  }

  constructor(_foo?: IFoo) {
    if (_foo === undefined) return this;
    Object.assign(this, _foo);
    this.moo = Object.assign({}, _foo.moo);
  }
}
```

Declaring a class in TS will at the same time create a type of the same name for you, which is the interface of its instance. So in your example, `FooModel` as a type is pretty much identical to `IFoo` interface that you manually declared.

As a precautionary measure, I also create a utility type `PropertiesOnly` to help stripping off any potential methods that presents in `FooModel`.

The other optimization is to use `Object.assign` to un-verbose the code, so you don't have to type out those properties repeatedly.

Comment: This might help for bigger objects _(which I have)_, thanks!

Comment: Deriving the type from the concrete class makes having `IFoo` fairly pointless. As it only has the props, consumers cannot access any methods `FooModel` might have via `IFoo`. It also breaks things like interface segregation (classes implementing multiple different interfaces, so consumers are only aware of the properties and methods they need).

Comment: @jonrsharpe so you would suggest that this isn't a really good solution for the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe As a pragmatist I don’t really have an opinion on whether it’s good or bad. It’s a solution after all, so it might have its place somewhere. As of IFoo not having methods, you see I intentionally remove them, I think OP want that.

Comment: If you don't understand and articulate the costs and benefits, that isn't pragmatism so much [programming by coincidence](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence). To put it another way: pragmatism is a lens for making trade offs, you still have to know what trade off you're making. It doesn't absolve all responsibility. If you don't know what it makes easier and harder you're beyond intentfully accrued tech debt and into bankruptcy!

Comment: Wow man, eh, I think you interpret my intention a bit too much. I don't have any context of OP's real problem, I just provide a thought that's all...He asks for shorter code so I give that. If he doesn't like the solution he can choose not to use it, it's up to him to decide.

Comment: And yeah I understand the benefit of interface oriented way of coding. But I'm not sure whether OP actually want it or perhaps he simply doesn't know it's possible to derive `IFoo` from `FooModel` for one time use.